# How to download file(s) from remote server directory to local machine in PuTTY?

Tags: putty

How to download file(s) from remote server directory to local machine in PuTTY ?

I got the command for inserting file to remote directory from local machine. But it is not working for me though there is no error message.

pscp c:\documents\foo.txt fred@example.com:/tmp/foo

Comment: Are you sure this is a question suited for StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Question is probably more suited to Superuser)

You have your parameters in the wrong order. Please refer to the documentation:
https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp

To **download**, you need:

```
pscp [options] [user@]host:source target
```

What you have there is the opposite, it's for doing an **upload**.